# MySQL reset AUTO_INCREMENT in a transaction

Tags: php, mysql, sql, transactions

### Some background

I have a DB table, using InnoDB, that will only ever have 8 rows. It made sense to use (unsigned) tinyint for the primary key. Now the data for the table comes from an external source and the table is basically a cache for that data. Every 24 hours (or so) we need to fetch new data, remove the old data from the table and fill it with the new one. While this is happening we want the previous data to be available for other connections so it makes sense to use a transaction and commit at the end. Now, it turns out `TRUNCATE TABLE` resets the `AUTO_INCREMENT` but it is considered a DDL and commits automatically and can't be part of a transaction so we use `DELETE FROM TABLE`. But that doesn't reset `AUTO_INCREMENT`. So, we will run out of IDs the 32nd time this happens.

### The actual question

I need a way to reset `AUTO_INCREMENT` for a table as part of a transaction. Can't use any DDL commands like `TRUNCATE TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE` etc. as they are applied immediately and not part of a transaction.

Comment: In your scenario I wouldn't use AUTO_INCREMENT at all.

Comment: if it were possible, you could hack up the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value in `information_schema.TABLES`, but that pseudo-db is read-only. The only practical way is to do your `ALTER`. That or don't use a tinyint. since you need more than 0-255, use a bigger field, e.g. int or bigint.

Comment: @VMai Hmm, you're suggesting a primary key without `AUTO_INCREMENT`. If so what do I insert in the PK column with each row? `INSERT INTO table(id,...) VALUES(SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM table, ...)`? `AUTO_INCREMENT` feels more natural, doesn't it?

Comment: See the answer of Bill Karwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, there's no way to reset the auto-increment without using DDL.

But you can insert any value you want with DML, overriding the auto-increment.

So you could generate your 8 id values manually.

For example, here's one method:

```
SET @id = 0;
INSERT INTO little_table VALUES
(@id:=@id+1, 'data'),
(@id:=@id+1, 'data'),
(@id:=@id+1, 'data'),
(@id:=@id+1, 'data'),
(@id:=@id+1, 'data'),
(@id:=@id+1, 'data'),
(@id:=@id+1, 'data'),
(@id:=@id+1, 'data');
```

Note that this has a race condition if you have more than one thread reloading data into this table. I.e. both sessions could try to insert the same values. But I assume you have control over that, and you're reloading data only in one session at a time.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. And it actually made the inserts a little faster.

Comment: Thanks for that concern about a race condition. There will only be one thread doing this. Also, the whole thing is done as part of a transaction so it's all or nothing.